# Occasional artifacts when displaying characters

Tags: drivers, ati, firefox, fonts, radeon

**To summarize the answer:** switching to proprietary drivers should work, but the artifacts disappeared for me even on the free drivers now.

**Update:** since switching back to the proprietary AMD driver (fglrx), I haven't seen these artifacts.

Occasionally I see artifacts instead of correctly rendered characters:

[image]

For now I have only observed this in Firefox.

The characters become normal once I select the text.

What's the issue here and how can I solve it?

Graphics card:  AMD Radeon HD 7790
Driver: radeon (free) -> now I'm no fglrx and am not seeing the artifacts (see the update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen these artifacts on two completely different machines (MacBook Pro using Nvidia and desktop using Radeon HD7750). They started appearing after upgrading to 13.10 and 14.04. I've been using 12.04 previously, and had never seen these artifacts on these machines.

Apparently common factor was using open-source drivers, artifacts have disappeared completely when I switched to Nvidia proprietary driver (via "additional drivers") and AMD Catalyst downloaded directly from AMD (fglrx from "additional drivers" didn't seem to work for me on 14.04).

Comment: Huh, so basically, no solution for now? OK then, at least something isn't broken on my system.

Comment: Well installing proprietary drivers is the good enough solution for me. The bug has been around for a while. If you'd add your comment here it would be helpful. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1314551

Comment: I switched to the free drivers again and I stopped seeing the artifacts. Weird.