# Firefox glitched glyphs

Tags: firefox, fonts

When browsing with Firefox, some pieces of text will randomly render with bizarre glyphs, which immediately go away if selected or some other action happens on the page or even outside of it. For example, the simple fact of taking this snapshot triggered the numbers to render normally:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Note that this can happen on any character, even simple ascii ones like in the pictures, and the glitched glyphs which appear instead of the correct ones are not always the same.

I'm on an up to date Kubuntu 14.04 with noscript, flashblock, ghostery and adblock on Firefox. I had to install some fonts to display Korean characters previously, and I can't remember having this bug beforehand

As requested, here's the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAPE VERDE
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:<nothing here>
```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/492489/occasional-artifacts-when-displaying-characters - I seem to be having a similar issue, except my artifacts look a bit different, and have to be selected in order to be cleared.

Comment: Well 99% of the time they are cleared upon selection, and some of my artifacts do indeed look like yours. radeon hd 7770 here BTW

Comment: Well then, it's a race to the top :D I'll keep an eye on your question as well. The first one of us that gets an answer should flag the other's question as a duplicate, by the way (of course, if the solution works for both).

Comment: Hey @nathdwek, could you tell me which graphics driver you are using? Post the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`.

Comment: I have [switched to fglrx](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492489/occasional-artifacts-when-displaying-characters) briefly and haven't seen the artifacts (glitches) since. Could you test this out? To  enable it, just type "drivers" in the Dash and open the Additional Drivers application (might take a while) - and select the one that has fglrx in its name. It takes a while and I suggest you reboot after the procedure.